# Why does make update precompiled headers sometimes, but not always?

Tags: c++, makefile, dependencies, gnu-make, precompiled-headers

**THE FILES**

foo.hpp

```
#include <iostream>
class foo
{
public:
    foo(int = 1);
    int get_x() const { return x; }
private:
    int x;
};
```

foo.cpp

```
#include "foo.hpp"
foo::foo(int xp)
{
    x = xp;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "foo.hpp"
int main()
{
    foo bar;
    std::cout << bar.get_x() << std::endl;
}
```

Makefile (this is overkill for such a simple example, but I want to use something like this)

```
SHELL = /bin/bash
CC = g++
CPPFLAGS = -MMD -MP
SRC = $(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJ = $(SRC:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE = main

all: $(SRC) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(OBJ) -o $@

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $^

-include $(SRC:.cpp=.d)
```

**OBSERVED BEHAVIOR**
The files are 20K. Run `make`, output is 1 and files are 48K. Now change default argument `int = 1` in header file to `int = 2`.
`make`: output is 2 and files are 11M. Nearly all of that is in foo.hpp.gch. Change `int = 2` to `int = 3`.
`make`: output is still 2, foo.hpp.gch did not update.

Now if I move `#include <iostream>` out of foo.hpp and into main.cpp:
Files are 20K. Run `make`, output is 1 and files are 48K. Change `int = 1` to `int = 2`.
`make`: output is 2 and files are 1.9M, nearly all of that in foo.hpp.gch. Change `int = 2` to `int = 3`.
`make`: output is 3, foo.hpp.gch *did* update.

**QUESTIONS**
Why does `make` update a precompiled header (.gch) in one case, but not in the other? Why are the file sizes so different? What happened to the content of `iostream`? And how can I force `make` to always take into account changes in header files? I tried adding `-fsyntax-only` to `CPPFLAGS`, per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50773946/3100212), but that gave an error.

Comment: Where is the rule to generate the precompiled header?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin the Makefile is exactly as shown.

Comment: gcc docs at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html  list a bunch of limitations affecting use of precompiled headers, including a couple of reasons their content or size can vary.

Answer (score 0):

To partially answer my own question, in the Makefile I changed `$^` to `-o $@ $<` and that seems to fix everything. The header files now update every time, and the combined files are only 144K. I got this idea [here](https://gribblelab.org/teaching/CBootCamp/12_Compiling_linking_Makefile_header_files.html#org5a8ea04).